# Proper way to read if else logic in conditional rendering ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm just barely learning reactJS and got a little confused for reading an if else in the conditional rendering that I've been written. This is the code that I've wrote:

```
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    })
    axios('https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=USA&results=5').then(response => this.setState({
        users : response.data.results,
        loading : false
      }))
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getUser()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          {!this.state.loading ?
          this.state.users.map(user =>
             <div>
               <h2>{`${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}`}</h2>
             </div>) : 'Loading'}
          {console.log(this.state.loading)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

When the program is still reaching for the API data, a 'Loading' string will be displayed and when the program already get the API data, it will disappear and displayed the data instead

I'm doing trial and error for the part in `render()`. first I put `this.state.loading` without `!` (false) and the app just displaying Loading all the way with no end. But when I put `!` (false), the program works just fine.

So I got confused on how to read the if else statement in this occurence, like

> If `this.state.loading` condition is false (with `!`), write the `<h2>`. Else display 'Loading' string

But the problem is, the condition of `this.state.loading` before the API data obtained is true, since I wrote it before in here:

```
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    })
    axios('https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=USA&results=5').then(response => this.setState({
        users : response.data.results,
        loading : false
      }))
  }
```

Then why the Loading is working? Please tell me how to actually read this logic, thank you before.

Comment: You should initialize the loading state to true, not set it to true later. You can also do `{this.state.loading ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : this.state.users.map(...)}` to make it less convoluted.

Comment: @ChrisG Obviously, it will make it less convoluted, I just want to sharpen my basic logic. Thank you, I already figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state.loading == true ? console.log("still loading") : console.log("loaded");
```

you could check the value like this

try to change

```
!this.state.loading
```

to

```
this.state.loading == true
```

so if the loading state is equal to true it will display "still loading", and if the loading state is set to false it means that the ajax request is done and it will display "loaded".

Comment: @AleksanderJockovic Thank you, your example and explanation does made me figured it out!